# How do you get Dropbox shareable links from the API?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, c#-4.0, dropbox, dropbox-api

We have a web application that uses dropbox as file storage. We have currently run into the issue that shortlinks become inactive after 31 days (http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=33049). Therefore, we are looking for ways to create shareable links instead of shortlinks. However, we can't seem to find this in the API.

Also, it appears to use the funcationality to create a shareable link, you first have to visit a specific dropbox URL to enable something (http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=35225&replies=2#post-303557). Would this also need to be done via the API?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of writing, the user no longer has to have visit the specific link from that forum thread to enable the feature. Any link created using the /shares call yields a "shareable link" with the preview page. (These links are shortened with db.tt.)

Further, users who do have the feature enabled will automatically have non-expiring links, akin to the links they can create manually. There is currently no API call to create non-expiring links for users without the feature enabled.